# No funciona mostrar div haciendo click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, div

Es mi primer post aquí y espero que me puedan ayudar.

Estoy haciendo un recetario, y quiero que al buscar una receta me muestre en un href con el nombre, y al hacer click, que se despliegue un div con la información de la receta.
Mi problema viene al querer el mostrar el div. Implemente este ejemplo [xr9sw2p3](http://jsfiddle.net/1k7mnc04/5/) y varios como ese pero no me funcionan.
No se si puedo adjuntar el codigo porque estoy trabajando con una base de datos, pero así guardo los nombres en un href:
ACTUALIZADO CON LA RESPUESTA

```
while( $rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultado1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ){
     echo '<li>
              <a href="#recetaid" class="abrir">'.$rows['nombre'].'</a>
                <div class="receta">
                  <p>Información receta</p>
                </div>     
           </li>';
 }
```

Esto, esta dentro de una sección, y abajo puse esto para mostrar el div con la información (que aun no saco de la base de datos porque esto no me funciona):

```
 <div id="recetaid" style="display: none">
     <p>Información receta </p>        
 </div>
```

El script que hago es el siguiente:

```
<script>
    let abrir = document.querySelectorAll('a.abrir');
    abrir.forEach(function(item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function() {
            let receta = item.parentNode.querySelector('.receta');
            receta.classList.toggle('activa');
        });
    });
</script>
```

ADJUNTO FOTO DEL ESTILO.CSS
[image: estilo.css]

Cuando saco el **style="display: none"** del div, me muestra el div pero debajo de todos los nombres que he encontrado, no cuando hago click en el nombre, que es lo que quiero. Y cuando esta el display:none, no me muestra nada al hacer click.

[image: ejemplo]

No se si alguien me puede ayudar con este problema, ya que he probado muchas variaciones y no puedo solucionar esto.

Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

No uses ID dentro de un ciclo, porque se van a repetir y deben ser únicos. Basta con asignar clases para hacerlo funcionar.

- Asigna una clase a los enlaces, en este ejemplo `abrir`
- Otra clase para los divs mientras están ocultos `receta`
- Al hacer clic en el enlace los divs se muestran agregando la clase `activa`, o se ocultan si es que ya están visibles, eso hace `.classList.toggle()`

```js
// Ejecutar hasta que el documento se haya cargado
$(function() {
    // Asignar evento a todos los enlaces con clase "abrir"
    $("a.abrir").on('click', function() {
        // Cambiar la clase del div que contiene la receta
        // para mostrar u ocultar
        $(this).parent().find('.receta').toggleClass('activa');
    });
});
```

```css
.receta {
    display: none;
}
.activa {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#recetaid" class="abrir">Arroz</a>
        <div class="receta">
            <h2>Cómo preparar arroz</h2>
            <div>Aquí ingredientes y procedimiento</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#recetaid" class="abrir">Huevo con salsa</a>
        <div class="receta">
            <h2>Cómo preparar huevo con salsa</h2>
            <div>Aquí ingredientes y procedimiento</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Tu código PHP es correcto y debería generar una salida HTML como en el ejemplo del fragmento de arriba, entonces, probablemente estás cargando y ejecutando javascript antes de que se genere el HTML y tienes dos opciones:

1. Colocar la etiqueta javascript hasta abajo, antes de `</body>`
2. Hacer que javascript se ejecute después de que se cargó todo el contenido

```
    <?php
    while( $rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultado1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ){
        echo '... lista ...';
    }
    // Aquí más código HTML/PHP
    // Solución 1
    ?>
    <script src="nombre_de_tu_script.js">
    </body>
    </html>
```

```js
// Solución 2, ejecutar hasta que se haya cargado el DOM (HTML)
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    let abrir = document.querySelectorAll('a.abrir');
    abrir.forEach(function(item) {
        // item es el enlace en que se hizo clic
        item.addEventListener('click', function() {
            // Desde item, retrocedes al elemento de lista (parentNode)
            // Ahí se busca el div usando querySelector y la clase
            let receta = item.parentNode.querySelector('.receta');
            // Mostrar / ocultar div
            receta.classList.toggle('activa');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hice lo que me puso acá:
- Cree un estilo. css para agregar lo de receta y activa.
- puse el div dentro del while asi como me dijo.
- e hice el script
Me muestra los href, pero cuando le doy click no me aparece el div.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta, colocando tus códigos actualizados.

Comment: Listo, lo actualice. Gracias por ayudarme :)

Comment: @ValeAsencioUribe, listo, respuesta actualizada

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS! Si funciono!!

Comment: hay alguna forma de hacer ese script como era el que yo tenia?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a hacerlo con jQuery? Sí, es posible, pero con algunos cambios. Mañana lo intento.

Comment: si, a eso. Que el script que me enviaste, lo entiendo pero no estoy familiarizada con el. Por eso te preguntaba si se podía con JQuery.

Comment: Listo, ya quedó

Comment: MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS! No sabes como te lo agradezco =D Ojala poder enviarte un mensaje para agradecerte mejor!!!